# Redirect from aspx to silverlight xaml

Tags: silverlight-4.0

Redirect from aspx to silverlight xamlPage I am usng siverlight application.

I am using the folowing code
HtmlPage.Window.Navigate(New Uri("/View/Pages/ActiveTaskPage.xaml", UriKind.Absolute))

it's not working..

Can any one help me out..

Comment: Why are you try to redirect xaml file.. Just call .XAP file object.. It will displayed .XAML file content..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make a silverlight application within a new aspx page and give link to that aspx page where the silverlight application is hosted.

Use this link: http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/raj1979/host-silverlight-in-Asp-Net/

Answer (score 0):

Silverlight 4 comes with tools, controls and functionality that is impossilbe to implement in ASP.NET. Companies are already building cool Silverlight controls. Currently, I am working on a Website where we have to build some Silverlight custom controls and integrate these controls with ASP.NET 4.0 application.

This article describes how we can integrate and host Silverlight controls in an ASP.NET application.

First of all let's make a new Silverlight project and put whatever you like in it; you can use my code for testing.

Here is my `MainPage.xaml`

```
<UserControl x:Class="SLTestExample.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
     xmlns:sdk="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation/sdk">
    <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="White" Margin="-146,-105,-145,-109" Height="500" Width="800">
        <sdk:DatePicker Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="183,159,0,0" Name="datePicker1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120" />
        <sdk:Calendar Margin="312,149,200,73" d:LayoutOverrides="Width"/>
        <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Left" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Welcome Raj Kumar" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="179,125,0,0" Width="158" Foreground="#FFC82C2C" FontWeight="Bold" FontStyle="Italic" FontSize="13.333"/>
        <Rectangle Fill="#FF9B9BC2" Height="100" Stroke="Black" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
        <Rectangle Fill="#FF83A16B" Height="30" Stroke="Black" VerticalAlignment="Bottom"/>
        <Rectangle Fill="#FFC2AF9B" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Stroke="Black" Width="175" Margin="0,104,0,34"/>
        <Rectangle Fill="#FF747370" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Stroke="Black" Width="186" Margin="0,104,0,34"/>
        <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Left" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="This is header" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="63,11,0,0" Width="263" FontSize="24" FontWeight="Bold" FontStyle="Italic"/>
        <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Left" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="This is footer" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Margin="60,0,0,7" Width="263" FontSize="13.333" Foreground="#FFE5EFEF"/>
        <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Left" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="This is left bar" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="8,106,0,0" Width="157" FontSize="13.333" Foreground="#FFE5EFEF"/>
        <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Right" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="This is right bar" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="0,106,18,0" Width="157" FontSize="13.333" Foreground="#FFE5EFEF"/>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

Now just run the application to see the result. and

Now put this code to the .aspx page.

```
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div id="silverlightControlHost">
    <object data="data:application/x-silverlight-2," type="application/x-silverlight-2" width="100%" height="100%">
          <param name="source" value="ClientBin/SLTestExample.xap"/>
          <param name="onError" value="onSilverlightError" />
          <param name="background" value="white" />
          <param name="minRuntimeVersion" value="3.0.40818.0" />
          <param name="autoUpgrade" value="true" />
          <a href="http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=149156&;v=3.0.40818.0"  style="text-decoration:none">
                   <img src="http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=161376" alt="Get Microsoft Silverlight" style="border-style:none"/>
          </a>
    </object><iframe id="_sl_historyFrame" style="visibility:hidden;height:0px;width:0px;border:0px"></iframe></div>
    </form>
</body>
```